# If a class is by default a subclass of class Object and if it is a subclass of another object then doesnt this become multiple inheritance?

Tags: java, object, multiple-inheritance

In java every class is by default a subclass of class Object
And we can extend any class to only one class.
So if a class is by default a subclass of class Object and if it is a subclass of another object then doesn't this become multiple inheritance?

Comment: A class inherits anything from its super class, including the methods and variables the super class did inherit from its super class.

Comment: A class is only a subclass of the class Object IF it is not subclass of an other class. Otherwise you would be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not:

```
class Object {}

class Parent /* implicit extend of Object class */ {}

class Child extends Parent /* explicit extend of Parent and so extends of Object */ {}
```

It is pure inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

This is chained inheritance, not multiple inheritance. Just because your parent class has another parent class doesn't make it multiple inheritance. Multiple inheritance is when you have two parent classes.